# z-index confusion in IE

Tags: jquery, css, z-index

I have a line of floated divs which reveal a popup when hovered over. The trouble is the popup appear under the following divs and I can't work out a way to use z-index to eliminate this problem... nothing seems to work.

EDIT: With help i've fixed the problem but not in IE7 or below.

Any one any ideas??

HTML

```
<div>

    <div>
        <img src="/bc.jpg" width="54" height="54" id="bc-icon" alt="test1" />
        <span><strong>test1</strong><br />dfgsertsrytwsertyrtyrsty</span>
    </div>

    <div>
        <img src="/bb.jpg" width="54" height="54" id="bb-icon" alt="test2" />
        <span><strong>test2</strong><br />dsfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfg</span>
    </div>

    <div>
        <img src="/rd.jpg" width="54" height="54" id="rd-icon" alt="test3" />
        <span><strong>test3</strong><br />dfgdfgdsfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfg</span>
    </div>

    <div>
        <img src="/bl.jpg" width="54" height="54" id="bl-icon" alt="test4" />
        <span><strong>test4</strong><br />dsfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfg</span>
    </div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
div {clear:both; padding:0 0 8px 0; border:none; width:576px;}

div div { float:left; margin: 0 8px 0 0; padding:0; width:56px; clear:none; overflow:visible; position:relative; background-color:#B22222;}       

div div img { padding:1px; cursor:pointer; display:block;}

div div span { background-color:#89A7BA; position:absolute; bottom:26px; left:-19px; padding:5px 10px; font-family:'MS Sans Serif',Geneva,sans-serif;  border:2px solid #FFF; font-size:12px; display:none;}

div div span img { position:absolute; bottom:-18px; left:34px;}
div div span strong {font-size:14px; text-transform:uppercase;}
```

and jquery to create the popups...

```
$.fn.hoverAnimation = function() {
    return $(this).each(function() {
        return $(this).hover(function() {
            $(this).find("span").slideDown(100);
            $(this).css("background-color", "#000");
        }, function() {
            $(this).find("span").slideUp(100);
            $(this).css("background-color", "#B22222");
        });
    });
}

$("div > div").hoverAnimation();
```

plus I've set it up in jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pnVC9/)

Comment: the popup should have some higner z-index,let me know if you need anything else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are quite right - IE7 won't run this correctly. The problem is that IE7 works out z-indexes based on the z-indexes of containing elements which need to be explicitly set. Every time you `position` something it will affect it's z-index. This puts you in a slight predicament. You would normally set the parent element to `position:relative; z-index:1` to reset the z-indexing but this won't work in your case as you need to set it on the first div and all the child divs (since you use `position: relative` on these). When you set it on the child divs they begin a new z-index stack which leaves you in the same predicament.

But I have a potential solution. Only set `position: relative` on the child divs when the jQuery is firing. See [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/7TEyy/)

Comment: I just had a pretty much the same idea, but altering the z-index of the other elements on hover at the time of firing the jquery. Seems to work a treat. Thanks

Comment: no worries :) - I think my solution could be easier to manage in the long run and use less mark up. But then I would! ;D

Answer (score 1):

solution to your problem any greater no should be fine

```
span {z-index:200}
```

working copy here

http://jsfiddle.net/dfgsH/

Comment: have you tried that in IE.? I think there's a z-index bug in IE7 which involves setting parent elements to have a higher z-index or something...

Comment: @Tom no , z-index works on all browsers , let me try in IE8 , i have olny ie8 in my compture

Comment: @Tom its working fine in ie8 also , logic should be like this , z-index of popup should be greater than parent div , thats it, that will show over the parent div

Comment: the problem is only with IE7 and below, but that's what the majority of my audience will be using.

Comment: @Tom , i have ie7 in the office , i can probably test there and fix the problem , i did z-index stuff many times ,butnever ran into this problem , go to this paage http://www.art.com/gallery/id--c1837/vintage-art-prints.htm?ui=9BB7055B6A9846D4A941B9E2356B42F0 and mouseover any image